# Add onclick tag on a link when input selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a search input that is displayed when the mouse is hover the search icon.
the search icon was not clickable so i tried to add an onclick on the link to trigger the search.
But when i try this solution on mobile, as i don't have mouse on mobile, when i select the search icon, it trigger the search without input filled by any word.

here is the html:

```
<div class="search-container">
    <form method="get" id="searchform">
        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="<?php echo $search; ?>">
        <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="search" onclick="document.getElementById('searchform').submit();"
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/search-icon.png" alt="Search" />
        </a>
    </form>
</div>
```

here is the CSS:

```
.search-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  width: 37px;
  -moz-transition: width 0.35s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.35s;
}
.search-container:hover {
  width: 20em;
}
.search-container:hover input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;

}

.search-container input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  float: left;
  width: 0em;
  margin-right: -42px;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  color:#333;
  -moz-transition: width 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.25s;
}
.search-container input:focus {
   outline: none;
}
.search-container img {
    float: right;
    background-color: #df5927;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

How can i activate the click on the search icon only when the input is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow a different aproach.
If you click the icon and the input has no value, show the input, otherwise submit the form

You have to move your click handler in a new function and not inline in the `<a>` element

So you listen for the click on the `<a>` element

```
document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

And then when the a is clicked you check if the input has any value and either submit it or show the actual input

```
function handleClick(event){
  var input = document.querySelector("input[name='s']");
  if(input.value.length == 0){
    //dont submit and show input for mobile
  } else {
    // input has value, submit form
    document.getElementById('searchform').submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly on Android mobile and PC, but, have an issue with Iphone. The click is not handle when text is filled in the input, really strange

Comment: @MarcElBichon can you see if some element overlaps the icon when the input is expanded?

Comment: nop, but after some tests, the issue appears to be only on iphone 5. it's strange, but i can leave with that, thank you for your time.

Comment: @MarcElBichon no problem. just try the z-index=999 hack just to be sure that its on the top of the layers